Trying to send SMS to USA
First off I appreciate your time and help if you can give it..
I am reasonably new to Twilio.  I am part of a start-up that is using Twilio SMS to deliver questionnaires to selected individual phones (with the users consent).  Company is based in Ireland so we use an Irish Twilio Phone number (+35386xxxx format). This works well in Ireland, and have also tested for sending SMS to UK and other countries (which works fine).
I now want to test sending to USA (+1).  However I get the error 21612 (Message cannot be sent with the current combination of "To" and/or "From" parameters). So I am trying to see what I need to do to fix this.  I have reviwed the Twilio support documents but I seem to be going down rabbit holes and/or around in circles.  Current Twilio number
Can anyone advise on the sequence of steps that I should try first?  I have seen the articles about getting verification for Toll-free numbers but this is not a toll-free number (or is it?)
The alternate for now is to have 2 different numbers for this service - one for USA (and Canada) and one for the rest of the world.  However I want to avoid that if possible as it then thows up a lot of extra complications down the line.
Thanks,
RoryF
I have reviewed this document (https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/21612) but I am unsure s to what applies to my situation

The problem you are describing is a regulatory one and less a programming-related one. So I try to keep this answer as brief as possible to avoid that it's outdated when regulations of any country changes again.
Generally speaking, it's always best to send SMS from the same country code that your users are using. This increases the trust and is usually the cheapest option to send and receive messages.
So in your case, it'd be best to send the message from US-based +1 numbers to a US Twilio number. For this, you need to comply with the US regulations by following the A2P 10DLC process (Application to Person, 10 Digit Long Code)

Thanks for the reply IObert.  At least now I know which track I need to follow.  I have had success using the Irish number sending SMS to some other 3rd countries (UK, Australia, etc..) but I guess I need to be cautious in that any 3rd countries can at any time implement restrictions such as those found in the USA/Canada.
